# Какой существует способ расположить элементы (блоки) в две колонки?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

При этом, если высота кончается, то добавляется Scroll

Идея в том, чтобы расположить элементы в две колонки, не учитывая высоту самого большого блока. Т.е. использование UniformGrid не особо подходит. Желаемый результат покажу на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо стандартных средств WPF, можно использовать telerik (может в нём уже существует готовый компонент).

Вот такой код я пробую написать, но видимо надо создавать кастомную Panel

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleCategories}"
                      Margin="32,40"
                      IsTabStop="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="modularity:MyType">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            Margin="5"
                            Padding="5">
                        //Тут Grid, разделённый на строки
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Алгоритм заполнения хотелось вы видеть такой: Заполняется первый столбец, затем когда кончается высота, заполняется второй; когда заполняется и второй столбец, но не все блоки ещё появились, то увеличивается высота панели, и следующий блок добавляется в первый столбец и так далее.

Это был мой первоначальный вариант. Но со временем он мне показался сложным и я подумал о том, чтобы заполнять так, чтобы каждый следующий блок ставился в самый низкий столбец

Comment: Делаете любой ItemSource элемент, переопределяете ему панель на WrapPanel и задаете стиль самого элемента, где ограничиваете ширину, все, у вас будет такое поведение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ что значит "Задаёте стиль самого элемента?"

Comment: Например `<ListBox><ListBox.ItemTemplate>(стиль)</ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>`, простое переопределение стиля элемента, его отображения в UI.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я добавил пример кода, но так и не понял, на какой стиль надо поменять. Подскажите?

Comment: Во, вроде [это вам нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25349425/6808809), там есть пример с переопределением панели и при помощи этого можно сделать то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Находил эту ссылку, быстро не получилось завести. Попробую порасбираться.
Спасибо большое!

Comment: Неплохо бы написать алгоритм заполнения панели. Ставим каждый следующий элемент в самый низкий столбец? Или заполняем столбцы по очереди? Или как-то ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишем панель:

```
class SimpleColumnStackPanel : Panel
{
    public int Columns
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Columns),
            typeof(int), typeof(SimpleColumnStackPanel), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    // Этап подсчета занимаемого места
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return ArrangeInternal(availableSize, isMeasureStep: true);
    }

    // Этап размещения элементов
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return ArrangeInternal(finalSize, isMeasureStep: false);
    }

    private Size ArrangeInternal(Size size, bool isMeasureStep)
    {
        // Меньше чем 1 колонка быть не должно
        var columns = Math.Max(1, Columns);

        // Ширина колонки
        var columnWidth = size.Width / columns;

        // Здесь будем хранить текущую высоту каждого столбца
        var heights = new double[columns];

        // Перебираем все элементы
        foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
        {
            // Выбираем самую низкую колонку на данный момент
            var column = IndexOfMin(heights);

            if (isMeasureStep)
            {
                // Запрашиваем измерение желаемого размера
                child.Measure(new Size(columnWidth, size.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                // Размещаем элемент
                var x = size.Width * column / columns;
                var y = heights[column];
                child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, columnWidth, child.DesiredSize.Height));
            }

            // Увеличиваем колонку на высоту элемента
            heights[column] += child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        // Берем максимальную высоту колонки
        var maxHeight = heights.Max();

        // Если элементов не много — растянем панель по высоте на все доступное пространство
        if (!isMeasureStep && size.Height > maxHeight) maxHeight = size.Height;

        return new Size(size.Width, maxHeight);
    }

    private int IndexOfMin(double[] source)
    {
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
            if (source[i] < source[index]) index = i;
        return index;
    }
}
```

Используем ее:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <c:SimpleColumnStackPanel Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Height="{Binding Value}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Для теста я использовал такую простую вью-модель:

```
class MainVm
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; } = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item("1", 123),
        new Item("2", 248),
        new Item("3", 203),
        new Item("4", 97),
        new Item("5", 33),
        new Item("6", 27),
        new Item("7", 116),
        new Item("8", 38),
        new Item("9", 42)
    };
}

class Item
{
    public string Caption { get; }
    public int Value { get; }

    public Item(string caption, int value)
        => (Caption, Value) = (caption, value);
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]